# Post to Tumblr API with R - Error "fromJSON" only for photo posts

Tags: r, api, social-networking, tumblr

I have been working with R to post to tumblr through their API. I use the R package tumblR. Everything works fine for text- and link posts but I keep getting errors when trying to post photos.

Not sure what the issue is here, maybe some wrong syntax the way I insert the link for the photo? Tried to debug but could not solve it. Was hoping you guys can help me?

I am also posting the code for text and link posts, maybe some of you see value in this for yourself.

[R CODE]

```
require(tumblR)
require(httpuv)

### Authorize
consumer_key <-'key'
consumer_secret <- 'secret'
appname <- 'appname'
tokenURL <- 'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token'
accessTokenURL <- 'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token'
authorizeURL <- 'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize'

app <- oauth_app(appname, consumer_key, consumer_secret)  
endpoint <- oauth_endpoint(tokenURL, authorizeURL, accessTokenURL)
token <- oauth1.0_token(endpoint, app)
sig <- sign_oauth1.0(app, 
                     token = token$credentials$oauth_token, 
                     token_secret = token$credentials$oauth_token_secret)


### Post Text
post(base_hostname = "blogname.tumblr.com", type = "text", state = "published", tags = 'tag', 
     body = 'this is the body', token = token, consumer_key = consumer_key, consumer_secret = consumer_secret)

# => Shows: "* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache" but posts the textpost to tumblr


### Post Link
post(base_hostname = "blogname.tumblr.com", type = "link", state = "published", tags = 'tag', url_link= 'www.somelink.de',
     title_link= 'linkTitle', description= 'this is the description', token = token, consumer_key = consumer_key, consumer_secret = consumer_secret)

# => Shows: "* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache" but posts the linkpost to tumblr


### Post Photo
post(base_hostname = "blogname.tumblr.com", type = "photo", tags = "tag", caption_photo = 'photoTitle',
     link = "http://bilder.bild.de/fotos/bde-logo-35166394/Bild/20.bild.png",
     source_photo = "http://bilder.bild.de/fotos/bde-logo-35166394/Bild/20.bild.png", data_photo= NA,
     token = token, consumer_key = consumer_key, consumer_secret = consumer_secret)

# => Shows the following error and doese NOT (!) post the photo:

# * Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
# *   Trying 66.6.41.23...
# * Connected to api.tumblr.com (66.6.41.23) port 80 (#0)
#   > POST /v2/blog/blogname.tumblr.com/post HTTP/1.1
#   User-Agent: RCurl
#   Host: api.tumblr.com
#   Accept: application/json
#   Authorization: ...
#   Content-Length: 490
#   Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
#   
#   * upload completely sent off: 490 out of 490 bytes

#   < HTTP/1.1 401 Not Authorized (!!!!!!)

#   < Server: nginx
#   < Date: Sun, 22 Mar 2015 12:14:43 GMT
#   < Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
#   < Transfer-Encoding: chunked
#   < Connection: close
#     * Closing connection 0

#   Warning message:
#     In if (class(token) != "Token1.0") stop("token must be a Token1.0 type") :
#     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

#   Error in fromJSON(http.connection(url, token, bodyParams, consumer_key,  : 
#                                       error in evaluating the argument 'content' in selecting a method for function 'fromJSON': Error: Not Authorized
```

For what I researched, tumblr API might just return "401 Not authorized" because the syntax of the request is not correct, it does not have to be related to the authorization (key, secret etc.) itself. As the same credentials work for text and link post, I believe it should be a different problem.

tumblR description says either us "data_photo" or "source_photo", so I guess NA for one of them is ok. Tried both anyway.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

A new version (1.1) of tumblR has been released.

With this version:

- the dependency from the ROAuth package has been eliminated;
- the "post" function with "photo" type has been fixed;
- the warning message about token has been removed.

Thanks for reporting!